# Is it possible to load data on Scroll in WPF Combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am developing a wpf application. I have lots of data in my database. I am loading data through Web API in Combobox. So I need to load 50 records on scroll always.

Is it possible to load data on scroll in WPF Combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement data virtualization, there's [a good article about it here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization).

Answer (score 1):

Need to add trigger action of between VerticalOffset and ScrollableHeight  of scroll.

Example:

```
if (bar.VerticalOffset >= (bar.ScrollableHeight - 1))
{
      LoadData();
}
```